# Resource recommendation - Simultaneous DC Stark and Zeeman Effects

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, resource-recommendations

I am looking for resources treating the problem of simultaneous DC Stark and Zeeman Effects for arbitrary directions of the magnetic and electric fields (not necessarily orthogonal or parallel).
I am in particular interested in the effect of such simultaneous fields on atoms with hyperfine structure such as alkali.
Of course feel free to write an answer if you yourself know how to treat this problem.